# Converting retrieved Ember Data records into plain javascript objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model, in the route I would like to query the store, convert the results to pure javascript json objects. How can I achieve this? Bellow the route:

```
myApp.EunitsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
        return this.store.find('unit');
        // return this results as pure javascript objects
  },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        controller.set('units', model);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `DS.Model` to JSON representation, you can use [`toJSON` method](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_toJSON).

As `find('unit')` returns array, something like this should return array of JSON objects:

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.find('unit').then(function(units) {
    return units.map(function(x) { return x.toJSON(); });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but no luck, I am just getting an empty string when I alert the returned value from the controller

Comment: Hm it should work if `this.store.find('unit')` returns non-empty array of models... what do you obtain if you just try `return this.store.find('unit');` from `model` function?

Comment: The model has 6 records that are being loaded from the server when I call this.store.find('unit') in the model function. If I do a this.store.createRecord('unit'.. then I get an object in the array...

Comment: `store.find` returns promise array, which is empty until promise fulfills; my previous example did not take that into account. I fixed the example in my answer.